# Data won't update (database is SQL Server)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a problem in updating my data.

I have `Home.aspx.cs` and a class `HomeClass.cs`. I have a gridview in which I want to do my updating but it doesn't work.

It won't return the successful message and I also checked my SQL Server database but there's no changes.

This is my `Home.aspx.cs`:

```
protected void DataGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        GridViewRow row = DataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        // get old data
        HiddenField hidedescription = row.FindControl("hiddendescription") as HiddenField;
        HiddenField hidepkgcode = row.FindControl("hiddenpkgcode") as HiddenField;
        HiddenField hideoprcode = row.FindControl("hiddenoprcode") as HiddenField;

        // get new data
        DropDownList Ed_description = DataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Editdescription") as DropDownList;
        TextBox Ed_pkgcode = DataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Editpkgcode") as TextBox;
        TextBox Ed_oprcode = DataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Editoprcode") as TextBox;

        string Message = obj.Update_Data(Ed_description.SelectedItem,
                                            Ed_pkgcode,
                                            Ed_oprcode,
                                            hidedescription.Value,
                                            hidepkgcode.Value,
                                            hideoprcode.Value);

        Fill_Grid();
        Literal1.Text = Message;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

void Fill_Grid()
{
    try
    {
        DataGridView.DataSource = obj.Get_Data();
        DataGridView.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

And this is my `HomeClass.cs` class:

```
static string Connect = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONSTRING"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connect);
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataAdapter adap;
DataTable dt;

public string Update_Data(ListItem listItem,
                          TextBox Ed_pkgcode,
                          TextBox Ed_oprcode,
                          string hidedescription,
                          string hidepkgcode,
                          string hideoprcode)
{
    // update data
    string getnewType = listItem.Text;

    if (getnewType == "Data 1") 
    {
        getnewType = "Y"; 
    }

    if (getnewType == "Data 2") 
    { 
        getnewType = "N"; 
    }

    // old data
    if (hidedescription == "Data 1") { hidedescription = "Y"; }
    if (hidedescription == "Data 2") { hidedescription = "N"; }

    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Update PAORStdTime set type='" + getnewType + 
                       "', pkgcode='" + Ed_pkgcode.Text +
                       "', oprcode='" + Ed_oprcode.Text +
                       "' where type= '" + hidedescription + 
                       "' and pkgcode ='" + hidepkgcode + 
                       "' and oprcode ='" + hideoprcode +  "'" , con);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    return "Updated successfully";
}
```

Comment: How about letting your exceptions print to see what going on?

Comment: @Nin I've done it. It won't show me any exceptions thats why I'm lost now.

Comment: Empty `catch` clauses do waste both your time and our time.

Comment: BTW: [LITTLE BOBBY TABLES](http://bobby-tables.com/)!

Comment: @UweKeim I will put something in my `catch` clause. I'm not yet done with it for now. I think an empty `catch` clause is not the reason why I can't make my update work.

Comment: Getting rid of all `catch` is the best you can do.

Comment: @itsmePJ You've done what? If it doesn't return you the successful message then it should have encountered an exception somewhere before the `return` line. Please update your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
where type = hidedescription
and pkgcode = hidepkgcode
and pkgcode = hideoprcode
```

There is no way that `pkgcode` will be equal to both `hidepkgcode` and `hideoprcode`. I believe the code below is what you want.

```
where type = hidedescription
and pkgcode = hidepkgcode
and oprcode = hideoprcode
```

Comment: Hi @Rawitas I already edit my post, I also noticed that. I change it now. It still doesn't work. I wonder what's wrong with it.

Comment: Could you try running the query in SSMS?